# module.filename is undefined (Sequelize, Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I reading [this](https://scotch.io/tutorials/getting-started-with-node-express-and-postgres-using-sequelize) tutorial for Sequelize and Node.js. I get the following error on line 4:

TypeError: Path must be a string. Received undefined

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const basename = path.basename(module.filename);
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const config = require(`${__dirname}/../config/config.json`)[env];
const db = {};

let sequelize;
if (config.use_env_variable) {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable]);
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(
    config.database, config.username, config.password, config
  );
}
fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(file =>
    (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) &&
    (file !== basename) &&
    (file.slice(-3) === '.js'))
  .forEach(file => {
    const model = sequelize.import(path.join(__dirname, file));
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

It seems that the module.filename is undefined. I have no idea why that is (I am new to Node) and the only differences from the tutorial and my app are that I don't use the express api (but GraphQL) and my sequelize auto generated folders are located in ../postgres/ instead of ../

**Edit:**

If I run the tutorial repo and print `module.filename` I get `/Users/Creece/Downloads/postgres-express-node-tutorial-master/server/models/index.js`

Now if I manually assign the module.filename, like this: `module.filename = '/Users/Creece/Downloads/express_graphql_hmr_article_boilterplate-master/server/postgres/models/index.js';` (after the before the assignment of the basename constant) , I get a new weird error on the `const model = ...` line:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/Users/Creece/Downloads/express_graphql_hmr_article_boilerplate-master/server/dist/postgres/models/todo.js'
```

Note that the folder "dist" on the above path is webpack's (not sure about that though, it's just not mine).

**Edit 2: (Regarding my comment on @NikMartin's answer**

This is the autogenerated file by Sequelize ./postgres/models/todo.js:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {

  const Todo = sequelize.define('Todo', {
    title: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
  });



  Todo.associate = (models) => {
    Todo.hasMany(models.TodoItem, {
      foreignKey: 'todoId',
      as: 'todoItems',
    });
  };
  return Todo;

};
```

**Solution (based on the accepted answer):**

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
//const basename = path.basename(__filename);
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const config = require(`${__dirname}/../config/config.json`)[env];
const db = {};

let sequelize;
if (config.use_env_variable) {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable]);
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(
    config.database, config.username, config.password, config
  );
}

const models = [
  require('./Todo')(sequelize, Sequelize),
  require('./TodoItem')(sequelize, Sequelize),
];

models.forEach(model => {
  db[model.name] = model;
});

models.forEach(model => {

  if (db[model.name].associate) {
    console.log("entered");
    db[model.name].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

Comment: At line no 4 `module.filename` is undefined. How can you get filename in `module`

Comment: What is your node version ? `node -v`

Comment: @FrançoisP. the version is 6.10.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding the `module.filename` problem - you can read this discussion or just that comment: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1599#issuecomment-328540024

quote:

> aprilmintacpineda commented
>
> for those having this issue, it is also good to note that module.filename would be undefined if you bundled your files. In my case it was undefined and I fixed it by simply replacing it with __filename which yields the same outcome.

So you should be able to replace `path.basename(module.filename);` with `path.basename(__filename);`.

But it still would be a bundled js file in /dist folder and your models are in /postgres/models folder, as I understand.

### I see here two options:

1) To not to automatically load your models, but directly require all necessary models.

*assuming this file's path is `/postgres/models/index.js` and actual models are in the same folder*
*not tested*

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const config = require(`${__dirname}/../config/config.json`)[env];
const db = {};

let sequelize;
if (config.use_env_variable) {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable]);
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(
    config.database, config.username, config.password, config
  );
}

// removed autoloading block

// setting the list of used models
const models = [
  require('./TodoItem')(sequelize, Sequelize),
  require('./Comment')(sequelize, Sequelize)
];

// registering models by their names
models.forEach(model => {
  db[model.name] = model;
});

// using registered models to set up relations
models.forEach(model => {
  if (model.associate) {
    model.associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

This would mean less flexibility, but your bundled code would start to use bundled models. I guess it's not the best thing for a dist code to require some "external" (missing internal models) non config js files to work.

2) To load files not from a current folder but from a defined one.

- move `/postgres/models/index.js` out from the models folder to `/postgres/index.js` (so model folder would have only actual model files)
- remove `basename` from the file
- instead of `.readdirSync(__dirname)` use `.readdirSync(__dirname + "/../postgres/models")`
- remove `(file !== basename) &&` check (since it would be unnecessary)

Either way, replacing the module's properties (`module.filename`) should not be a solution.

Comment: First of all thanks for putting some time to help me with this issue. After lots of days I still can't figure it out myself.

Changing module.filename to __filename or using your 2nd proposed option get me this error:

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/Creece/Downloads/express_graphql_hmr_article_boilerplate-master/server/dist/postgres/models/todo.js'

Using the 1st option, I get:

Error: Todo.hasMany called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model

Comment: Adding to my above comment, it seems the 1st option actually works (I am seeeing the "INSERT INTO..." sql stuff on my console). Now the only problem is that the "Todo.hasMany" function returns an error. I am updating my question with that specific code.

Comment: @SkyPower, I'm not sure why you get "/d‌​ist/postgres/models/‌​todo.js" instead of "/d‌​ist/../postgres/models/‌​todo.js" in #2, since `.readdirSync(__dirname + "/../postgres/models")` should be in /dist directory as I understand. Regarding #1 - yes, db object should have all the models before association, going to fix the solution. Please let me know if I missed other things.

Answer (score 0):

And this can be simplified like this:

```
const config = require('../config/config')['development']
const {Sequelize} = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = new Sequelize(config['dbUrl']);
const db = {};
const models = [];

sequelize.authenticate()
    .then(() => console.log('Connection has been established successfully.'))
    .catch(err => console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err));

const modules = [
    require('./user'),
    require('./post'),
    require('./comment')
]

modules.forEach(module => {
    const model = module(sequelize, Sequelize)
    db[model.name] = model
    models.push(model)
});

models.forEach(model => {
    if (db[model.name].associate) {
        db[model.name].associate(db)
    }
});

module.exports = {...db, sequelize, Sequelize};
```